# PowerPoint animate/animation of BOTH Entry Effects and Exit Effects

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to add an entry effect and exit effect on a shape using VBA on PowerPoint.
I can't seem to get this right the documentation on this is bad to nonexistent.

Can someone please help me, if someone can just give me an example of this type of code that would be great.

I have tried all sorts of variations:

```vb
Sub newanimate_3()

    Dim PPSlide As Slide ' We need the slide object
    Dim tronShape As Shape

    ' Make sure a slide is selected

    Set PPSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    
    Set tronShape = PPSlide.Shapes("cur_1")

    ' Set the properties for the added picture
    With tronShape
        ' Set the position and size of the picture
        ' You may need to adjust these values based on your requirements
        '.Left = 100
        '.Top = 100
        '.Width = 200
        '.Height = 150
        ' Animate the picture
        With .AnimationSettings
            .EntryEffect = ppEffectFlyFromRight
            .AnimationOrder = ppAfterPrevious
            .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
            .AdvanceTime = 5 ' Start after 5 seconds
        End With
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Effect.Exit` property determines whether the animation effect is an exit effect.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim PPSlide As Slide ' We need the slide object
    Dim tronShape As Shape
    Set PPSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    Set tronShape = PPSlide.Shapes(1) ' modify as needed
    With tronShape.AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectFlyFromRight
        .AnimationOrder = ppAfterPrevious
        .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
        .AdvanceTime = 1 ' Start after 5 seconds
    End With
    With PPSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=tronShape, _
            effectId:=msoAnimEffectCircle, _
            trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
        .EffectParameters.Direction = msoAnimDirectionIn
        .Exit = True
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Effect.Exit property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.effect.exit?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm652016)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Sequence.AddEffect method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sequence.addeffect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm651004)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Slide.TimeLine property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.timeline?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm531031)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [TimeLine.MainSequence property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.timeline.mainsequence?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm649003)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)